# Шукаємо вдалий переклад терміну Deliverable

Tags: from-english, терміни

Перекладаємо PMBOK Lexicon та ISO Vocabulary в рамках проєкту "PMBOK та PM ISO українською".
Намагаємося підбирати прості переклади, але такі, що передають сенс оригінальних англійських термінів.

Для перекладу Deliverable в фінал вийшли такі варіанти (добре було б перекласти одним словом):

- набуток
- здобуток
- доробок
- результат, що поставляється
- кінцевий результат
- вихідний результат
- очікуваний результат

Визначення терміну Deliverable [там](https://www.pmi.org/-/media/pmi/documents/public/pdf/pmbok-standards/pmbok-guide-6th-edition-errata-4th-printing.pdf#page=14) таке:

> **Deliverables.** Any unique and verifiable product, result, or capability to perform a service that is required to be produced to complete a process, phase, or project. Deliverables also include ancillary results, such as project management reports and documentation. These deliverables may be described at a summary level or in great detail.

Comment: Тямку можна було сюди також винести i перекласти чи описати власними словами.

Comment: Так само [на фейсбуці](https://www.facebook.com/ukrse/posts/2954006624725364?comment_id=2954019924724034&reply_comment_id=2954028531389840) пропонують подивитися [Deliverable. Як це буде українською? / М. Д. Гінзбург // Стандартизація. Сертифікація. Якість. - 2015. - № 3. - С. 12–16](http://www.irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/cgi-bin/irbis_nbuv/cgiirbis_64.exe?I21DBN=LINK&P21DBN=UJRN&Z21ID=&S21REF=10&S21CNR=20&S21STN=1&S21FMT=ASP_meta&C21COM=S&2_S21P03=FILA=&2_S21STR=ssia_2015_3_3).